# Comparing two similar dataframes and filling in missing values of one dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, missing-data

So I have two dataframes, one is a single dataframe of a dictionary of dataframes `stocks['OPK']`, and the other is just a simple Pandas dataframe `df`.

Here is a slice of df,  `df.loc['2010-01-04':, 'Open']` that I'm interesting in comparing with the other dataframe.

```
Date          Open
2010-01-04    1.80
2010-01-05    1.64
2010-01-06    1.90
2010-01-07    1.79
2010-01-08    1.92
2010-01-11    1.90
2010-01-12    1.89
2010-01-13    1.82
2010-01-14    1.84
2010-01-15    1.85
2010-01-19    1.77
```

This is the other dataframe `stocks['OPK'].Open`

```
2010-01-04    1.80
2010-01-05    1.64
2010-01-06     NaN 
2010-01-07    1.79
2010-01-08     NaN 
2010-01-11    1.90
2010-01-12    1.89
2010-01-13    1.82
2010-01-14     NaN 
2010-01-15    1.85
2010-01-19     NaN
```

As you can, the second dataframe has missing values.

Since both indexes are of the datetime format, I want to be able to compare `stock['OPK'].Open` to  `df.loc['2010-01-04':, 'Open']`  and fill in the missing values with the values from the the first datframe, `df`

I can do a boolean filter with this code, but I don't know how to proceed from there:

```
stocks['OPK'].Open == df.loc['2010-01-04':, 'Open']
```

The problem with `pd.merge` and its respective options is that it seems to add extra 
columns. I just want to fill in the missing values (if there are any) through comparison of another dataframe which might have the missing values.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use fillna()

```
df2 = df2.fillna(df1)
```

Another and faster way is combine_first

```
df2 = df2.combine_first(df1)
```

Both will return

```
    Date    Open
0   2010-01-04  1.80
1   2010-01-05  1.64
2   2010-01-06  1.90
3   2010-01-07  1.79
4   2010-01-08  1.92
5   2010-01-11  1.90
6   2010-01-12  1.89
7   2010-01-13  1.82
8   2010-01-14  1.84 
9   2010-01-15  1.85
10  2010-01-19  1.77
```

Comment: Actually, both answers seem to work. My dataframe just had a mistake.
Thank you.

Comment: It seems that order doesn't matter? If I use d`f.fillna(df2)` or `df2.fillna(df)` both seem to yield the same answer unless I"m mistaken.

Comment: The order does matter as the first dataframe takes precedence. Only the missing values of the first dataframe will be filled by the true values of second dataframe